# dll reference conflict between C:\Windows\Assembly folder and Temporary ASP.NET folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dll

I am using DevExpress v10.2 in my application. After deploying my application in IIS of my production machine, i am getting an issue as 'The type DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.ASPxLabel' exists in two locations. One of the location is C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files contains DevExpress v12.2 dll and the other location is C:\Windows\assembly contains DevExpress v10.2 dll which is not letting the application to run. I have stopped the IIS and cleared the folders in "Temporary ASP.NET Files" folder and again tried running it, but resulted in the same issue. I have given the screenshot of my issue.

Please advise on solving this issue.

Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: what about your web config, does it hold references to both the devexpress versions

Answer (score 0):

Perform these steps:

1. Stop your IIS server. (go to inetmgr, right click your computer name in the left tree and select stop.)
2. Delete everything you have in C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files.
3. Start your IIS server again. (same as step one, but instead select start)

Comment: Hi amin, I have tried doing this already, but, it is not working. still getting the same issue in my production server. once i start IIS, after clearing the folders, all the references comes back to the Temporary ASP.NET Folder again.

Comment: Check this link http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q247503